# Triggering Javascript from a link on a previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of links on a services page that when clicked, reveal content relevant to the individual service. This is to save space on the page. I have done this using slide in JS.

On the homepage I also have a list of services that I would like to have linked the services page and then open up the relevant content dependant on service clicked on the homepage.

I'm a new user of Javascript so unfortunately this isn't something I could work out myself or find a solution for elsewhere. I would really appreciate somebody helping me to find a way of doing this.

Find below a short example of my code:

Homepage

```
<ul id='homepage-services-list'>
   <li><a href='services.php'>Service 1</a></li>
   <li><a href='services.php'>Service 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Services

```
<ul class='services-tabs'>

   <li class='services-tab'>
      <a class='service-1-trigger'>
         <div>
            <h3>Service 1</h3>
            <img src='images/down-arrow-icon.png'>
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>

      <article class='service-1-content'>
         <p>Content about service etc.</p>
      </article>

   <li class='services-tab'>
      <a class='service-2-trigger'>
         <div>
            <h3>Service 2</h3>
            <img src='images/down-arrow-icon.png'>
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>

      <article class='service-2-content'>
         <p>Content about service etc.</p>
      </article>

</ul>
```

Javascript - JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".service-1-trigger").click(function(){

       $(".service-1-content").slideToggle(600, function(){
           $(this).toggleClass("service-1-toggle").css('display',' ');
       });
   });

   $(".service-2-trigger").click(function(){

       $(".service-2-content").slideToggle(600, function(){
           $(this).toggleClass("service-2-toggle").css('display',' ');
       });
   });

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add anchors to your links.

```
<ul id='homepage-services-list'>
   <li><a href='services.php#1'>Service 1</a></li>
   <li><a href='services.php#2'>Service 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

With these anchors, you can extract from the URL the service wanted (1 or 2) and simulate a click with jQuery.

In your `document.ready` :

```
var url = document.location.toString();
if (url.indexOf('#') != -1) {
    var num_service =  url.split('#')[1];
    $(".service-" + num_service + "-trigger").click();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer my friend. It worked beautifully!

Comment: Ugh. Rather than firing synthetic events, have a common function both the click and the startup code call.

Comment: Also: Note that `url.match('#')` converts `'#'` to a regular expression (`/#/`) and then matches the string against it, creating a match array (if it matches). If you just want to see whether a string is `'#'`, just use `url == '#'` (not least because some characters are special in regular expressions).

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thank you for your remarks, I'll try to apply them :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I can't use url == '#' because I want to know if url var countains '#'. But I understood your point.

Comment: @Knriano: Then you'd use `indexOf` (or the new `String#includes`), or an explicit regular expression.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I didn't think of using indexOf, I edited my post :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to approach it:

1. On the home page, add fragment identifiers to those links:

   ```
   <ul id='homepage-services-list'>
      <li><a href='services.php#service-1'>Service 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='services.php#service-2'>Service 2</a></li>
   </ul>
   ```
2. On page load (inside your `ready` handler will do) look at `location.hash`. That is the current fragment identifier for the page. If it's one of your service identifiers, trigger the code showing that service.
3. You might also have your `click` handlers add the hash to the URL by setting `location.hash`, for consistency.

Look also at the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) for more control over hashes and URLs for in-page transitions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to contribute to a solution for me, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Short of switching to a SPA-type framework, there's no way for javascript on one page to directly affect a subsequently-linked page.

Two simple approaches to work around this are

- Cookie / localStorage:  Have your outgoing link set a cookie with a specific value for each link. The receiving page can check the value of this cookie and adjust as needed.
- URL hash: Include a hash value or parameter in the outgoing links, i.e. `<a href='services.php#service1'>`.  The receiving page can then check `location.hash` to read this value.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to contribute to a solution for me Daniel, much appreciated!